# Sending FILE data in a POST call

Tags: python, json, file

I have the following code:

```
email = 'david@gmail.com'
avatar = open('/Users/david/Desktop/a.png').read()
data = {
  'email': email,
  'avatar': avatar
}
body = json.dumps(data)
requests.post(url, headers=headers, data = body)
```

However, when I try doing that I get the following json error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

How would I send file data here?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, because `read()` isn't doing what you think it is:

```
>>> f = open('image.png').read()
>>> f
'\x89PNG\n'
```

Chances are it's reading up to the point where it reaches the first 'line', i.e. the newline character, and nothing more, as it does in my test above.

Additionally, if you're going to add png data to a JSON object, you will probably also need to convert to base64 or you'll get more invalid UTF8 characters.